# Store token in httpcontext and use the same token in another request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, token, httpcontext

I have a ASP.NET Core web application that hits a webservice endpoint and then that webservice sends requests to my application.

When I hit that webservice endpoint I receive a web token with a string value and expiry time. I am saving it in HttpContext to use it later.

When the webservice sends request to my application it sends the same token that I have received.

I need to make sure to validate that the token as it is the same that I initially received on my first request.

I do not want to store this token in my database because obviously I had to search the list of tokens and I can use a different token and as soon as it exists in the database this will work.

I have tried to store the token in `HttpContext.Items`

however, on request from the service to my app the token is gone. The Items have no token because I suspect it is a different `Httpcontext`.

On ASP .NET Framework I could store it as

```
HttpContext.Application["WebServiceToken"] = token;
```

However, I cannot find such an alternative on ASP .NET Core.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (serviceTokenService.TokenAlreadyExists())
        {
            return ArrivalsFromDatabase();
        }

        var exampleDate = new DateTime(2016, 3, 10);
        var callback = Url.Action("ReceiveArrivalInfoFromService", "Home", null, Request.Scheme);
        bool success = false;

        var token = await this.serviceTokenService.GetServiceToken(configuration["WebServiceUrl"], exampleDate, callback);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(token.Token))
        {
            this.serviceTokenService.SavesToken(token);
            success = true;
        }
        
        if (!success)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        return ArrivalsFromDatabase();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveArrivalInfoFromService()
    {
        var serviceToken = serviceTokenService.ReadToken();
        var isTokenValid = serviceTokenService.ValidateToken(Request, serviceToken);
        if (isTokenValid)
        {

            var arrivals = serviceTokenService.CollectArrivals(Request);
            await arrivalService.AddRangeAsync(arrivals);
        }
```

And this is my Servicetoken service where also my token method is.

```
public class ServiceTokenService : IServiceTokenService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public ServiceTokenService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }     

    public void SavesToken(ServiceToken token)
    {
        httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["ServiceToken"] = token;
    }

    public ServiceToken ReadToken()
    {
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["ServiceToken"] != null)
        {
            return httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["ServiceToken"] as ServiceToken;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

On ReadToken it returns null. The token that was received previously is lost because it does not exists in HttpContext.items.

Comment: what type of token are you using?

Comment: a custom one that has  a Guid string and expiry date

Comment: You could always store the token as a session or cookie and then use some middleware to add the token to each request.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of storing a value in your case the `ServiceToken` using a [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-session-state) and appending it to each request using [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Personally I would use [cookie authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or better yet IMO a [JWT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/), however to help get you started relating to your question, something like this should help get you started.

**First** - Create The Middleware.
I normally like to create a folder `Middleware` just so its nice and neat in the solution and then right click on the newly created folder > `Add` > `New Item` > `Middleware Class` and name your new middleware file. (ServiceToken)
Add add the following code, this will check the session to see if there is a key called `ServiceToken` if there is, it will add the `ServiceToken` value to the httpContext Request Header.

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    // Add Token To Context If Found.
    string token = httpContext.Session.GetString("ServiceToken");
        
    // Check Something Was Found.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        // Add The Custom Token Here.
        httpContext.Request.Headers.TryAdd("ServiceToken", token);
    }

    // Next.
    return _next(httpContext);
}
```

**Second** - Create The Session/MiddleWare, This is done in the `Startup.cs` file.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    // Add Session And Middleware Here.
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseServiceToken();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**Third** - Add the token to the service.
In your case your'e adding it within the index endpoint.
Something like this should get it started.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Get Token.
    string fakeToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";

    // Create Sercice Not If Not Already There.
    if (!this.HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("ServiceToken", out byte[] value))
    {
        this.HttpContext.Session.SetString("ServiceToken", fakeToken);
    }
    else
    {
        // Get The Token.
        string token = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value);

        // TODO: Validate Here Or In The Middleware.
    }

    return View();
}
```

**Note** - As you're creating the `ServiceToken` from index, the first time the pipeline is completed, there will be no token attached to the request, as it is adding if available before the endpoint is called, this means that it will be added to the request once the first cycle is complete.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that the httpcontext will have a new instance because it is called from the webservice... 
The token is generated when a call from the app to the service has been made. After this call requests from the service to a new endpoint in my app will be generated with token value in the header. I have to compare both tokens to make sure they match. Your idea is good but on my second request I have a new instance of httprequest.

Comment: `serviceTokenService.ReadToken();` is getting the token from the session,
`serviceTokenService.ValidateToken(Request, serviceToken);` is validating the token along with the httpcontext, at this point, I'm wondering why you're also passing the httpcontext when a token is already being passed? also, how are you validating the token?

Comment: Because token has expire time, I need to make sure the token has not expired. Also in the validate method I am getting the value of token from the header of the request and comparing it to the session we are talking which has another instance of a context.

Comment: In my ReceiveArrivalinfo method I have used ur logic that has trygetvalue from session.  I get this error:

{"String reference not set to an instance of a String. (Parameter 's')"}

Comment: sorry for the late reply, is `s` a null object?